# I can't obtain the screenshot of a JFrame that I want

Tags: java, swing

I have this code: `

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;


public class Provare extends JFrame {

    private JPanel contentPane;
    public static int x=100;
    public static int y=100;

    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    x=(int) (100+(x*(Math.random()*3)));
                    y=(int) (100+(y*(Math.random()*3)));
                    Provare frame = new Provare();
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                    BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(frame.contentPane.getWidth(),frame.contentPane.getHeight(),BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB );
                    frame.contentPane.printAll(image.getGraphics());
                    ImageIO.write(image, "bmp", new File("C:/Users/Resco/Desktop/scarpe/screen.bmp") );
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Create the frame.
     */
    public Provare() {
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setBounds(100, 100, x, y);
        contentPane = new JPanel();
        contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        contentPane.setLayout(new BorderLayout(0, 0));
        setContentPane(contentPane);
    }

    public void paint(Graphics g){
        super.paint(g);
        g.drawString("CIAO",(x/2),(x/2));
        g.drawLine(50, 50, 100, 100);
    }

}
```

`

What I'd like to get is a screenshot with the text CIAO and a line. 
What I actually get is a screenshot of an empty element.

Any suggestion? Feel free to post a modify version of my code.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You are printing `contentPane` contents on the image: `contentPane` has nothing to print, it's empty.

You have to use

```
frame.printAll(image.getGraphics());
```

**Side note**: You should not override the `paint` method from `JFrame` to perform custom painting. Override the `paintComponent` method from `JPanel` instead.

Answer (score 0):

My tip is, that your frame is not ready yet.  I would try to call `frame.setVisible(true)` in `EventQueue.invokeAndWait` and get the screenshot after from the main thread.